# onDraw method of the view is called too many times

Tags: android, performance, layout, pinchzoom, pinch

I have a HorizontalScrollView inside which I have multiple custom views. I am detecting pinch zoom event in HorizontalScrollView and passing the ScaleFactor to the child views. I want to scale the child views according to ScaleFactor provided by its parent.

So I am doing something like this.

There are two variables in child view: localScaleFactor and 
First I am getting parentScalefactor from its parent. Then in onDraw method of custom view I am doing like to scale the view

localScaleFactor *=parentScalefactor
canvas.scale(localScaleFactor , localScaleFactor);

But as my onDraw function is calling many times localScaleFactor is increasing very rapidly even though I am pinch zoo single time.

Parent pinch zoom Listener

```
        private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

               mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));
//sending pinch zoom event to its child index 'start' to 'last'
            for(int i=start;i<=last;i++)
            {
                LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout)pp.getChildAt(i);
                DrawView view=(DrawView)ll.findViewById(R.id.drawview);
                view.mScaleFactor=mScaleFactor; //setting child scalefactor
                view.invalidate();
            }


            return true;
        }
    }
```

Child view onDraw method

```
        public  float mScaleFactor = 1.f; //this will be set by parent viewgroup

 public  float sf = 1.f; //local scalefactor
    public float oldsf=1.f;
    @Override

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {


        sf=(mScaleFactor/oldsf);
        width=sf*700;
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        canvas.save();

        canvas.scale(sf , 1);

        Log.e("Ronak","DrawView "+sf);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE); 
        canvas.drawRect(r, paint);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawRect(r, paint);


        requestLayout();
        oldsf=mScaleFactor;

       }
```

Comment: How are you implementing the pinch?  A lot of time the touch events are continuously being sent during the pinch.  This means your code might detect a single pinch as actually a lot of multiple pinches in terms of two finger points moving closer together continuously.

Comment: @RazsApps
I have added pinch zoom code. Check if I am doing anything wrong. I have added relevant code only. So if you are not getting any part of code, please reply back

Comment: I don't have the exact answer since I've never directly worked with ScaleGestureDetector, but the other Gesture stuff I've worked with keeps sending the events over and over again as long as the user keeps his fingers on the screen and there is some movement. It also sent as a summation of the total movement which means I had to keep track of difference between each event. I suspect you are facing a similar issue.  So the total pinch might be a factor of 2.0 but you might receive multiple events at like 1.2, 1.5, 1.6, 1.9, 2.0 which means if you keep multiplying your actual factor is almost 11

Comment: @RazsApps
Ya, this is exactly I am facing. The problem with sending the difference is that my app won't be user friendly as it will scale only after I have terminate the gesture. You know how I can fix this behaviour.

Comment: Keep a variable for oldScaleFactor (which should be initialized as 1), which is the scale factor from the previous run through onDraw. But instead of scaling by the scale factor each run through, you should scale by the new scale factor divided by the old scale factor.

Comment: @JacksonKulik

Now it is not scaling at all. I have edited my code above. Please see if I am doing any wrong

Answer (score 0):

I see what it is now looking at the ScaleGestureDetector docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector.html#getScaleFactor%28%29 What happened is that the call to getScaleFactor() returns the scale factor for that given point in time rather than a summation as we had previously asserted. What made it seem this way was that your `mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();` should have been simply `mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();` Each time you would do that, the scale value applied each time would be the product of each individual scale factor encounter rather than the individual scale factor itself. If you go back to your old code without my previous suggestion and change the one line of code, I believe it should work properly. Sorry for the false trail earlier.
-Jackson